# How to remove the flow file attributes in Nifi flow file?

Tags: apache-nifi

[image]
Update Attribute configuration
[image]

Comment: I tried to configure my update attribute like something shown in the attached picture. It seems like not working. Also, I have attached content of my flow file. Please have a look.

Answer (score 5):

It is hard to tell from the screenshots provided, but it looks like the fields you want to remove are part of the content of the flow file, which is different then the attributes of the flow file. UpdateAttribute can only remove attributes, not anything in the content.

In order to modify the content you would need to use a processor specific to the type of content being processed. In your case it looks like JSON, so you could use a ConvertRecord processor with a JsonTreeReader and JsonRecordSetWriter, and configure the writer to have a different schema then the reader. Basically read in all the fields, but only write out the fields you want.

There is an UpdateRecord processor too, but it doesn't currently have the ability to remove fields.

Comment: Bryan,I tried ConvertRecord Processor. It worked. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a FlowFile's attribute, you can use `UpdateAttribute` and a property named `Delete Attributes Expression`. You just need to fill it with a regular expression that matches the attributes you want to remove.

But as @Bryan Bende said, it doesn't look like you're trying to remove FlowFile's attributes, but content..

If you are willing to remove JSON attributes from your content, you can use `JoltTransformJSON` and `Jolt Transformation DSL` of `Remove`. Then just use specification of the attributes you are willing to remove. For example, I want to delete from this JSON the attribute `t1`:

```
{
"t1": "test",
"t2": "test2",
"t3": "test3"
}
```

So, my specification would be:

```
{
    "t1": ""
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt).

Comment: Sure, I will use it in my next project. But thanks for jumping in giving an idea. Thanks.